# I can't remove the remnants of a program that failed to install completely and I can't install synaptic

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, uninstall

A program I tried to install failed to install 1 package and continues to fail regardless of what I try. I want to uninstall the rest of the program that was partially installed but my current attempts haven't worked. I have tried these commands in many orders:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get --auto-remove final_package_before_install_fail
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove final_package_before_install_fail
sudo apt --fix_broken install
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove final_package_before_install_fail
```

And many other variations with -f --ignore-missing and more

Trying to fix the dependencies just results in the the system attempting to install the uninstallable package and failing at that step. I want to install synaptic to remove packages with missing dependencies but it won't do anything even if I use ignore missing. I know the answer is probably out there but my search keywords aren't finding them. Manually uninstalling the packages would take a long time as there is 50+ (ok not forever)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and elaborate on "continues to fail regardless of what I try".  What are you trying, and what happens?

Comment: I explain what I did to try to remove the program and I said nothing happens, sometimes that is literally no output or just telling me the package that needs to be installed or just an error(1). I found an alternative to the program I was trying to install so I don't need to install it anymore, I just want to uninstall the remnants of it.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1289079/edit) to show us the complete output from the install failure. The details are important. The output is preserved in `/var/log/apt/term.log`. If the failure occurred before the month changed, then the failure is preserved in `/var/log/apt/term.log.1.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Despite the installed software not showing synaptic, it was installed anyway. Using synaptic I found the broken package and all packages that depended on it by going to status->broken dependencies and marking the main offending package for **Complete Removal**, then clicked apply and did

```
sudo apt autoremove.
```

This doesn't really help if you don't have synaptic when this happens unfortunately.

Comment: Please look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what commands exactly helped to clear up the mess. Synaptic is just a front-end for `apt` and `dpkg` commands, so there will be some valuable information there. If so, please add this to your answer.